# PHP exec output does not return and execute commands

Tags: php, windows, cmd, exec, youtube-dl

I am trying to execute a command in PHP on a Windows Server Machine.

The code i am using is:

```
<?php
$out = array();
exec('C:\libs\bin\youtube-dl -o "C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw"  "http://youtube.com/watch?v=SrMKY5Aoyrw"', $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

My result in PHP is:

```
Array
(
[0] => [youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading webpage
[1] => [youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading video info webpage
[2] => [youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Extracting video information
[3] => [youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading DASH manifest
[4] => [youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading DASH manifest
)
```

My result should be:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert>C:\libs\bin\youtube-dl -o "C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw" "http://youtube.com/watch?v=SrMKY5Aoyrw"
[youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading webpage
[youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Extracting video information
[youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading DASH manifest
[youtube] SrMKY5Aoyrw: Downloading DASH manifest
WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.
[download] Destination: C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw.f137
[download] 100% of 111.72MiB in 00:01
[download] Destination: C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw.f251
[download] 100% of 8.13MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw.mkv"
Deleting original file C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw.f137 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file C:\xampp\htdocs\API\jbb15\convert\SrMKY5Aoyrw.f251 (pass -k to keep)
```

The problem about this is: The exact same command as in the above PHP script works perfectly if the command is copied into the Windows CMD. There are no PHP error logs. The command --verbose will return nothing in PHP, but works in windows cmd.

Comment: Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: This returned the same problem. Difference: at the end was a "255".

Comment: You should try using it `--no-warnings` to ignore Warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for contributing. The problem was that i did not set `> msg.log 2> msg2.log`.

The line `WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.` was run in `2>` and therefore stopped the execution.

The command `--no-warnings` might have solved it too.